# LDAP is not connecting

Tags: php, ldap, openldap

I am using OpenLDAP and trying to connect (and bind) to ldap using the below mentioned PHP code from another server and its failing. But using this code, its connecting (and binding) successfully from the same server.

```
$ldaphost = "server_name";  // 127.0.0.1 when using same server and changing the value when using different server 

$ldapport = 389;

$ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldaphost, $ldapport);


if ($ldapconn) {
    echo 'Connected <br/>';

    $userdn = "cn=manager,ou=Team,dc=example,dc=com";
    $password = "password";

    $bind = ldap_bind($ldapchtgoponn, $userdn, $password);

    if ($bind) {
        echo "Bind Successful";
    } else {
        echo "Error in bind";
    }
}
```

Do i need to set anything to connect with LDAP from different server?

Answer (score 2):

not sure if you use OpenLDAP or other ldap-compliant server, but for OpenLDAP (slapd), you should not need to do any special configuration steps to be able to connect to the server from a remote machine - the server listens on all available network interfaces on ports 389 ( ldap:// ) and 636 ( ldaps:// - ldap over SSL ).

You can read more about network config for slapd [here](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/security.html).

I suspect you have either a network, DNS resolution or firewall problem.

Try using `telnet` to check the network connection from a terminal client or Command Prompt, like this:

`telnet YOUR_SERVER_ADDRESS 389`

You should get a bunch of nonsense from the ldap server and the telnet client should wait for your further input. If you see anything else, like *connection refused* and the telnet client exits it means there is firewall blocking your communication or you cannot contact the remote machine. Or, you have configured the slapd client to listen only on specific interfaces or IP addresses.

I recommend trying the telnet command with an IP address instead of DNS hostname to eliminate any possible DNS-related issues.

Comment: Yes, i am using openLDAP. Added this information in above post.

Comment: What's the result of the telnet? Have you tried it from the remote machine?

Comment: Yes, tried telnet from remote machine. Its displaying 'connection refused'.

Comment: Can you please suggest how to fix this? It will be useful for others as well.

Comment: Open ports 389 and 636 on your firewall. Check the firewall on your server and also make sure there is no dedicated firewall blocking the connection on the network - if you are on a company network, there might be. This is very OS-specific so I can't really suggest anything particular. Check your OS documentation for these steps. Also check your slapd config if the server is configured to listen on all network interfaces as already described in my answer.